# Compilation errors when using explicitly-typed enum classes in bitfields (gcc C++0x/C++11)

Tags: c++, class, enums, bit-fields

I've been happily compiling my code with GCC without issue for the past three months until I rebuilt my cross-compiler, which was when I found myself getting the message "error: bit-field '...' with non-integral type".

An example of an offending enum is below:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

enum class opStatus : byte
{
    /* Process has yet to begin execution */
    Ready,
    /* Process can resume execution */
    Started,
    /* Process has completed */
    Finished,
    /* Process is handling shutdown */
    Finishing,
};

struct // Example usage
{
    opStatus Status : 2;
};
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe you broke your cross-compiler, or forgot to build in C++11 support. Without seeing what you actually did, and without knowing what your compiler is, there's not much else to say here.

Comment: GNU GCC G++ 4.6.0 using config C++0x. And I've re-built the compiler a number of times using fresh sources.

Comment: Since this seems to be an issue caused by your cross-compiler, code from that compiler would be usefull to answer this.

Comment: Note that the code `struct  { opStatus Status : 2; };` will give compilation error anyway even if `opStatus Status : 2` is allowed in the language! You must introduce at least one name in the declaration. So write `struct tag_name { opStatus Status : 2; };`  or `struct { opStatus Status : 2; } object_name;`.

Comment: What code specifically would you suggest?

Comment: And yeah, I didn't bother giving it a name in the example :P

Comment: I just built GCC 4.7.1 and binutils 2.22, and under c++11 still get the same error.

Comment: Try to come up with a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

Make the bitwidth 8. Its a byte after all.

Once I did that (and added a name for the struct),

```
g++ -std=c++11
```

didn't give me any warning or error.